# Mongo auth but for only specific document

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication, usergroups

I have a monogo DB which I made an admin with

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myusename",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },{ role: "readWrite", db: "MYDB" }]
  }
)
```

But  I want to do authentication only when I want to connect to MYDB. Assume that I want to have other documents line SECONDDOC in MongoDB that it does not need authentication ( or even it could have another type of username and password if it needs to be authenticated to connect to mongo). How could I do it?

My mongo version is 3.6.3

Comment: That's not possible.  BTW, when you grant `{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }` then this user can grant anything to himself. So, in this combination the roles are pointless.

Comment: Thank you but what is the best way to do this? basically, I want to have two different databases with different users and access. How could I limit the use to access only one particular database?   Another thing that I forgot, is that if I go to mongo shell without login, I cannot even see the names of the database ( shows permission error). Do you know what possibly I have done? thanks

Comment: Your question was to make authentication for a specific **document**, now you ask for a **database**. Granting privileges on *database* or *collection* level is standard. Granting (only) role `{ role: "readWrite", db: "MYDB" }` grants read+write access to all collections in database `MYDB`. Anything else is not permitted for this user.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried! one of my problems is that I need to log in to mongo with a username and password (the user that has { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } permissions) otherwise if I just use mongo, I could not run any database. It looks somehow I locked the mongo shell that only let me log in and then can do manipulation in dbs or docs

Comment: But you know, that you have to create different users? At least one admin user and another different user with less privileges.

Comment: I think I got it thanks!'